# Как правильно тестировать исключение?

Tags: java, junit, тестирование

Есть некая функция DoIt, на которую пишется тест (JUnit). Если передать аргумент null, функция должна выкинуть исключение. Я проверяют так:

```
public final void TestDoIt() {
    try {
        // Вызываю функцию
        DoIt(null);
        fail("doit(null) должна выкинуть исключение");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}
```

Это правильно или можно как-то лучше?

Comment: работает?) вродь все просто и понятно, зачем себе усложнять жизнь?

Comment: Работает. Но уж больно много лишних строчек.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Это правильно для JUnit до версии 4.

В новых версиях можно (и нужно) использовать аннотации:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public final void doIt() {
    DoIt(null);
}
```